# Move data to production tables after Bulk Insert to stage table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, entity-framework

I have a database normalized like the one on the picture bellow. I store the clients, the accounts and the postal address for each account. As you can notice, the Client-Account relationship type is many-to-many, there for the ClientAccount table.

[image: normalized tables]

Since I have a database with 100k Account records I'm considering the use of SQL Bulk Copy. I think that I could use a stage table with all the fields of the tables above, and then normalize the data.

My problem is that I don't know how to move the data to the production tables. How can I create a stored procedure to perform this job, after the bulk insert import?

PS: The database is for as ASP .Net Web Site with the EF enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You must insert one table at a time in the right order

Address -> Account -> Client -> AccountClient

1. create the addresses:

   ```
   Insert into Address(data)
   Select distinct address_data From temp
   ```
2. Account

   ```
   Inser Into Account(account_number, address_id)
   Select t.account_number, a.id From temp t
   Inner Join Address a on a.data = t.address_data
   ```
3. Client

   ```
   Insert into Client(name, client_number)
   Select distinctname, client_number From temp
   ```
4. Client Account
       Inser Into ClientAccount(accountId, clientId)
       Select a.accountId, c.clientId From temp t
       Inner Join Client c on c.name = t.name and c.client_number = t.client_number
       Inner Join Account a on a.account_number= t.account_number

Make sure:

- you don't create duplicate if some of the data are already there
- you match on rows between real and temp table on the right columns